# How Inherit from a baseComponent Angular2?

Tags: javascript, angular, angular-services

I am building a angular project. 
I want to create a BaseComponent with common functionality. 
For example: I have a TeacherIndexComponent:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-teacher-index',
  templateUrl: './teacher-index.component.html'
})
export class TeacherIndexComponent implements OnInit {
  public teachers : Profesor[];

  constructor(private _otherService: OtherService
              private _teacherService: TeacherService,
              private _messageService : MessageService) {

   }

  ngOnInit() {
   this._otherService.doSomething();

    this._teacherService.getTeachers()
                .subscribe(teacherData => this.teachers= teacherData,
                           error => this._messageService.showErrorMessage(error));

  }
```

In every components I have to inject **OtherService**. I want to create a BaseComponent. In this component should inject **OtherService** and in its ngOnInit() call to this._otherService.doSomething();
This baseComponent has not a template (html) only functions, I need to use its events functions (ngOnInit, ngOnDestroy).
All component extends to BaseComponent:

```
export class TeacherIndexComponent extends BaseComponent implements OnInit {
```

and BaseComponent implement OnInit too:

```
export class BaseABMComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(private _otherService: OtherService) { 
  }

  ngOnInit() {
       this._otherService.doSomething();
  }
```

This is similar to BaseController, Is possible build it in Angular ? Or I should repeat code in every component ?

Thanks very much!

Answer (score 1):

If you inherit `BaseComponent` with implementing own `OnInit` in order to call `BaseComponent.ngOnInit` you need to call `super.ngOnInit()` inside currently implemented `ngOnInit` method (in your case `TeacherIndexComponent.ngOnInit`)

Comment: Ok, so using BaseComponent isn't transparent. Every component must call super.ngOnInit() in your ngOnInit() :/

Comment: It is not a Angular's feature. That is how inheritance works in (probably) all languages (not frameworks).